# Natural Sort Grocery Crud results

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, grocery-crud

Grocery Crud provides the function order_by:

```
void order_by(mixed $order_by [, string $direction] )
```

However the field I need to sort is a varchar and I need to perform natural sorting. The MySQL query which correctly sorts the list is as follows:

```
ORDER BY 0+'field_name' ASC
```

Is there any way to specify '0+' in Grocery Crud?

thanks

Comment: Not sure, but how about $crud->order_by('CONCAT(0,field_name)','ASC');

Comment: Can you left pad the column value with enough 0's to ensure that all numbers in the column will have the same string length?